# We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, terminal

In localhost my projects works perfectly but every time I deploy to heroku I receive Something  went wrong..... I also ran Heroku run rake db:migrate. Any idea what is going on here?

```
2015-11-01T23:27:52.203020+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-11-01T23:27:52.203020+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-11-01T23:27:52.203072+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:27:52] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-11-01T23:27:52.203127+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-11-01T23:27:52.532296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 41390 -e production`
2015-11-01T23:27:52.897623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-11-01T23:27:58.070739+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:27:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-11-01T23:27:58.070767+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:27:58] INFO  ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26) [x86_64-linux]
2015-11-01T23:27:58.071119+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:27:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=41390
2015-11-01T23:27:58.474379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-01T23:27:59.642521+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-11-01T23:27:59.642524+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:41390
2015-11-01T23:27:59.642526+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-11-01T23:27:59.642527+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-11-01T23:27:59.642527+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 186.7.194.9 at 2015-11-01 23:27:59 +0000
2015-11-01T23:27:59.766836+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2015-11-01T23:27:59.799012+00:00 app[web.1]:   Listing Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings"
2015-11-01T23:28:00.392668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=first-2015.herokuapp.com request_id=926437db-f38c-4e20-bd41-214c5a3c23e4 fwd="186.7.194.9" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=776ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-01T23:28:00.357900+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 591ms (ActiveRecord: 43.1ms)
2015-11-01T23:28:00.357305+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (561.8ms)
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379967+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379972+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/original/1_maxresdefault.jpg' not found):
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379974+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379975+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <div class="col-md-3">
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379975+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <div class="thumbnail">
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379976+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:       <%= image_tag listing.image.url %>
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379976+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:       <div class="caption">
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379977+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:         <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379978+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:         <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price)%></p>
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379979+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_listings_index_html_erb___3544290808032810079_70137168564260'
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379980+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb___3544290808032810079_70137168564260'
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379980+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379981+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:28:35.183269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-11-01T23:28:37.475572+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45138 -e production`
2015-11-01T23:28:39.679694+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150522+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:28:41] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150526+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150528+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in start'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150529+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150530+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150530+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150531+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150532+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150533+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150534+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150535+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150535+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150536+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150537+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150538+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150616+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:28:41] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150667+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:28:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-11-01T23:28:41.150693+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-11-01T23:28:42.127027+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-11-01T23:28:42.240828+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:28:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-11-01T23:28:42.240888+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:28:42] INFO  ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26) [x86_64-linux]
2015-11-01T23:28:42.241276+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-01 23:28:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=45138
2015-11-01T23:28:42.749478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-01T23:28:43.792876+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-11-01T23:28:43.792882+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:45138
2015-11-01T23:28:43.792883+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-11-01T23:28:43.792884+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-11-01T23:28:43.792884+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 186.7.194.9 at 2015-11-01 23:28:43 +0000
2015-11-01T23:28:43.852744+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2015-11-01T23:28:43.871140+00:00 app[web.1]:   Listing Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings"
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=first-2015.herokuapp.com request_id=801454af-a367-44c0-813d-11682425132c fwd="186.7.194.9" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=503ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-01T23:28:44.289069+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (421.4ms)
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290295+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:28:44.289266+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 436ms (ActiveRecord: 9.3ms)
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290297+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/original/1_maxresdefault.jpg' not found):
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290299+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <div class="col-md-3">
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290299+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290301+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:       <%= image_tag listing.image.url %>
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290300+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <div class="thumbnail">
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290302+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:         <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290303+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:         <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price)%></p>
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290302+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:       <div class="caption">
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290305+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb__2061699741869559202_69894874271620'
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290304+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_listings_index_html_erb__2061699741869559202_69894874271620'
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290306+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:28:44.290306+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:35:20.887734+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 186.7.194.9 at 2015-11-01 23:35:20 +0000
2015-11-01T23:35:20.894377+00:00 app[web.1]:   Listing Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings"
2015-11-01T23:35:20.890439+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
2015-11-01T23:35:21.264843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=first-2015.herokuapp.com request_id=7c3a22ea-957b-49f6-83d5-6d639dae83f2 fwd="186.7.194.9" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=380ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-01T23:35:21.258765+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (366.5ms)
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263640+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263643+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/original/1_maxresdefault.jpg' not found):
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263644+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263645+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <div class="col-md-3">
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263646+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <div class="thumbnail">
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263646+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:       <%= image_tag listing.image.url %>
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263647+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:       <div class="caption">
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263648+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:         <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263649+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:         <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price)%></p>
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263651+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb__2061699741869559202_69894874271620'
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263650+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:6:in `block in _app_views_listings_index_html_erb__2061699741869559202_69894874271620'
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263651+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:35:21.263652+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-01T23:35:21.261958+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 371ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Comment: The error that seems to keep repeating is `Path '/original/1_maxresdefault.jpg' not found`

Comment: Are you using the paperclip gem?

Comment: Yes im using paperclip gem

Answer (score 0):

This is your error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/original/1_maxresdefault.jpg' not found):
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379974+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379975+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <div class="col-md-3">
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379975+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <div class="thumbnail">
2015-11-01T23:28:00.379976+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:       <%= image_tag listing.image.url %>
```

The problem seems to be that the path for your `listing.image.url` was unrecognised.

I'm not sure why Rails is treating this as a fatal error (normally, it will just show the HTML `img` with a "not found" image), but in this case, it's causing the entire Rails application to fail.

---

The workaround (to get this working) is to **remove `<%= image_tag listing.image.url %>`** from your `app/views/listings/index.html.erb` file.

This won't be a fix, but should resolve the immediate problem.

---

The *fix* will be two-fold (I'm not entirely sure what the cause of the issue is):

> 1. Ensure your Paperclip files are intact
> 2. Ensure your DB has the correct references

The issue seems to be that `/original/1_maxresdefault.jpg` doesn't exist.

This image name is used by YouTube, so I suspect you're either lifting Youtube cover images or trying to mimick YouTube's video processing structure.

Either way, the folder structure you should have in your app is as follows:

`public/system/[model]/[attachment]/[other_options]/[sizes]/[file].[extension]`

It seems to me that your path isn't being called properly, or that you don't have the correct filename inside it. You may have manually populated the filename or something.

I would personally remove the entire `/public/system` folder (it is Paperclips'), remove all the references to attachments in your db and go through all my `listings` to upload new images.

I would then make sure that `public/system` is present in the git push (you can ensure this by checking it is not in `.gitignore`), and then pushing to Heroku again.

-

Also make sure Heroku's db structure mimicks your development environment - it may be the case that an image referenced in the *production* db is not present.

Comment: you mean to delete all the content in the public/system? and then to try to upload new images?

Answer (score -1):

You should download rails_12factor gem.

https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor

This will help you understand your heroku logs a lot better.